# Laravel - Expected response code 250 but got code "550", with message "550 not local sender over smtp

Tags: laravel, email

I use mail.ru service for mailing. But when I submit for email this gives me this error

this is my .env

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mail.ru
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=support@domain.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=******
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=no-reply@domain.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME=Ali
```

this my ContactMailer.php

```
namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class ContactMailer extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public array $data;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->from('no-reply@domain.com', 'Admin')
            ->view('emails.contact')->with('data', $this->data);
    }
}
```

this is my Controller method

```
public function send(Request $request): \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
    {
        try {
            $data  = [
                'header'  => 'domain.com - contact',
                'name'    => $request->get('name'),
                'email'   => $request->get('email'),
                'phone'   => $request->get('phone'),
                'message' => $request->get('message'),
            ];

            Mail::to('support@domain.com')
                ->send(new ContactMailer($data));

            return Redirect::back()
                ->with('alert','Success');

        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            Log::info($e);
            dd($e);
            return Redirect::back()
                ->with('alert','Fail !');
        }
    }
```

[image]

I already wrote sender in ContactMailer.php
for example I change all paramaters to my old working projects configurations. But not working yet. What I missing ?
Do you have any solutions ?

Comment: Do you get anything about the sub error number? Have a look at the following: https://www.enginemailer.com/blog/email-error-550-what-is-it-and-how-to-fix-it

Comment: @Peppermintology there isn`t sub error number.. I already checked this link. But my program not exists in this link

Answer (score 0):

fixed by adding env key to ContactMailer.php

```
public function build()
    {
        return $this->from(env('MAIL_USERNAME'), 'Admin')
            ->view('emails.contact')
            ->with('data', $this->data);
    }
```